# Table with with different fields depending on category

Tags: entity-framework, database-design

I have table that has these columns:

```
Id
Title
Description
CreateDateTime
CategoryId
Picture
quantity
Price
RentPrice
WantToExchange
NumberOfRoom
DepositPrice
```

Only the first 6 are required for each row and other column will be null based on entity category.

For example in `cat1` only first 6 field and `Price` filled by user,and in `cat2` only first 6 field and `RentPrice, DepositPrice` are filled, so after a while many column of table rows become a null

I see some solution in NopCommerce source code that used for store various product property in different language - there are entity called [LocalizedProperty](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/develop/src/Libraries/Nop.Core/Domain/Localization/LocalizedProperty.cs) and storeEntityId, LanguageId, Name of entity, name of field and its value
[it use](https://github.com/nopSolutions/nopCommerce/blob/860f6cf0821f6bbd955b8f4ffc530ad56ddc5cb1/src/Libraries/Nop.Services/Localization/LocalizedEntityService.cs#L254)

```
Expression<Func<T, TPropType>>
```

and `PropertyInfo` to get name of field, but I am searching for an easier way.
How can I redesign my entity?

Comment: Have you considered using Inheritance?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft i think this is nice solution ,tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd have designed this object orientedly, you would probably have create a `PictureDescription` class, and a `PicturePrice` class, that would have the other properties.

Every PictureDescription would **have** zero or one PicturePrice object: a straightforward aggregation

If you want zero-or-one in a relational Database, then this is quite often done using two tables, with a foreign key from one table pointing to the other table.

See [Entity Framework zero-or-one-to-one](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-one-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

```
class PictureDescription
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Title {get; set;}
    ...

    // every PictureDescription has zero or one PicturePrice
    public virtual PicturePrice PicturePrice {get; set;}
}

class PicturePrice
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    ...

    // every PicturePrice belongs to exactly one Picture, using foreign key
    public int PictureDescriptionId {get; set;}
    public virtual PictureDescription PictureDescription {get; set;}
}
```

This will be enough for entity framework to detect your columns and the relations between the tables. If you want to use fluent API, in DbContext.OnModelCreating:

```
// every PictureDescription has zero or one PicturePrice:
modelBuilder.Entity<PictureDescription>()
    .HasOptional(description => description.PicturePrice)
    .WithRequired(price => price.PictureDescription)
    .HasForeignKey(price => price.PictureDescriptionId);
```

Comment: thank you for your replay,but there is no problem with picture,you may dont understand my question well,my problem is that some rows not contain all of this filed,for example there are many row that hase  Price, but not RentPrice nor WantToExchange and this field become null in table